# Gitlab CI/CD: missing /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner. Uploading artifacts is disabled

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, artifacts, runner

So I have a quite simple gitlab-ci.yml script:

> ```
> test stage:
>
>     stage: build 
>         artifacts:
>             paths:
>                 - result/
>     script:
>         …
> ```

So the problem is when it gets to the “Uploading artifacts for successful job”, it prints “Missing /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner. Uploading artifacts is disabled”.

Tried to change an owner and a group of the gitlab-runner file to “gitlab-runner”, even gave 777 rights, but nothing helped.
Any ideas where I’m wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gitlab latest version, it will be installed in /usr/bin/gitlab-runner, but you are trying to use /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner.